# OpenCV - Access pixel from image in mousecallback

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to implement a mouse callback in OpenCV and print the intensity value to the console. I tried the following:

```
void mouseHandler( int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param ) {

if( event != CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    return;

cv::Point point = cv::Point( x, y );
cv::Mat *img = (cv::Mat*) param;
uchar val = img->at< uchar >( point );
std::printf( "x: %i y:%i val: %u\n", x, y, val ); 
}
```

the call to this is:

```
cv::setMouseCallback( "imageName", mouseHandler, &img);
```

When I click in the image, my program crashes.
I tried to only print the coordinates and this works just fine. Apparently the program crashes when I try to access the image values...

I have a single channel CV_8U image:

```
img.convertTo( nImg, CV_32FC3 );

cv::cvtColor( nImg, hsvImg, CV_RGB2HSV_FULL );
cv::split( hsvImg, channels );

channels[2].convertTo( chan, CV_8U );
cv::setMouseCallback( "chan", mouseHandler, &chan );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post how do you create your image ? Here you access to the image as if the image contains Integer. Most of the time an image contain unsigned char... So how do you create your image ?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I changed my question - the problem is still the same

Comment: have you tried swapping y for x : `cv::Point point = cv::Point( y, x );`?

Comment: Do you have problem accessing variable chan OUTSIDE mouseHandler? I think the problem is in the construction of chan, if you can show the code snippet on this bit.

Comment: thank you james - you are right! I contructed chan in a function and therefore the scope of the variable is just in this function - haven't thought about that...